# Aggregate query over multiple columns (one is an array) in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to get aggregates values for each att1, and att2 column, and also for each value of the arrays in att3 column.

As far I tried:

```sql
create table test(value Float32, att1 String, att2 String, att3 Array(String))
 ENGINE=MergeTree() ORDER BY ();
```

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2.0, 'a', 'Z', ['sports', 'office', 'anothertag'])
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4.0, 'b', 'X', ['sports', 'office', 'tag'])
INSERT INTO test VALUES (6.0, 'b', 'X', ['sports', 'internet', 'planes'])
```

```sql
SELECT * from test;
```

```
┌─value─┬─att1─┬─att2─┬─att3───────────────────────────┐
│     6 │ b    │ X    │ ['sports','internet','planes'] │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴────────────────────────────────┘
┌─value─┬─att1─┬─att2─┬─att3─────────────────────────────┐
│     2 │ a    │ Z    │ ['sports','office','anothertag'] │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
┌─value─┬─att1─┬─att2─┬─att3──────────────────────┐
│     4 │ b    │ X    │ ['sports','office','tag'] │
└───────┴──────┴──────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

I want to get the aggregate -sum(value)- for each different attribute.

I have it working for att1 and att2 columns with:

```sql
SELECT
    att1,
    att2,
    sum(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY
    att1,
    att2
    WITH CUBE
```

Result:

```
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─sum(value)─┐
│ b    │ X    │         10 │
│ a    │ Z    │          2 │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┘
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─sum(value)─┐
│ a    │      │          2 │
│ b    │      │         10 │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┘
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─sum(value)─┐
│      │ Z    │          2 │
│      │ X    │         10 │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┘
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─sum(value)─┐
│      │      │         12 │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

Which gives me more than needed, but results two and three give correct results.

But I also need the value for each value on att3, I have it working in another query, but when trying to make a single query:

```sql
SELECT
    att1,
    att2,
    arrayJoin(att3) AS tags,
    sum(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY
    att1,
    att2,
    tags
    WITH CUBE
```

Which gives (among other things):

```
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─tags─┬─sum(value)─┐
│ a    │      │      │          6 │
│ b    │      │      │         30 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────┘

┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─tags───────┬─sum(value)─┐
│      │      │ tag        │          4 │
│      │      │ anothertag │          2 │
│      │      │ planes     │          6 │
│      │      │ sports     │         12 │
│      │      │ internet   │          6 │
│      │      │ office     │          6 │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Since arrayJoin 'unfolds' array into rows, now values of sum(value) in att1 are not accurate.

I've also tried the `LEFT ARRAY JOIN` syntax with same results.

Updated:

The ideal result would be something like:

```
┌─'att1'─┬─'att2'─┬─'tags'─┬─'sum(value)'─┐
│    a   │        │        │         2    │
│    b   │        │        │         10   │
│        │    X   │        │         10   │
│        │    Z   │        │         2    │
│        │        │ sports │         12   │
│        │        │ office │         6    │
│        │        │ anot.. │         2    │
│        │        │ tag    │         4    │
│        │        │internet│         6    │
│        │        │planes  │         6    │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────────┘
```

Could be in different rows (results), but ideally in one single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the more straightforward way is to combine two queries:

```sql
SELECT
    att1,
    att2,
    '' AS tags,
    sum(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY
    att1,
    att2
    WITH CUBE
UNION ALL
SELECT
    '' AS att1,
    '' AS att2,
    arrayJoin(att3) AS tags,
    sum(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY tags

/*
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─tags───────┬─sum(value)─┐
│      │      │ internet   │          6 │
│      │      │ sports     │         12 │
│      │      │ office     │          6 │
│      │      │ tag        │          4 │
│      │      │ planes     │          6 │
│      │      │ anothertag │          2 │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┴────────────┘
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─tags─┬─sum(value)─┐
│ b    │ X    │      │         10 │
│ a    │ Z    │      │          2 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────┘
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─tags─┬─sum(value)─┐
│ a    │      │      │          2 │
│ b    │      │      │         10 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────┘
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─tags─┬─sum(value)─┐
│      │ Z    │      │          2 │
│      │ X    │      │         10 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────┘
┌─att1─┬─att2─┬─tags─┬─sum(value)─┐
│      │      │      │         12 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴────────────┘

*/
```

Comment: Simply, clever. It's a bit performant that other answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    sumMap(([att1], [value])) AS r1,
    sumMap(([att2], [value])) AS r2,
    sumMap((att3, replicate(value, att3))) AS r3
FROM test
┌─r1─────────────────┬─r2─────────────────┬─r3──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ (['a','b'],[2,10]) │ (['X','Z'],[10,2]) │ (['anothertag','internet','office','planes','sports','tag'],[2,6,6,6,12,4]) │
└────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘



SELECT
    (arrayJoin(arrayZip((arrayJoin([sumMap(([att1], [value])), sumMap(([att2], [value])), sumMap((att3, replicate(value, att3)))]) AS r).1, r.2)) AS x).1 AS y,
    x.2 AS z
FROM test
┌─y──────────┬──z─┐
│ a          │  2 │
│ b          │ 10 │
│ X          │ 10 │
│ Z          │  2 │
│ anothertag │  2 │
│ internet   │  6 │
│ office     │  6 │
│ planes     │  6 │
│ sports     │ 12 │
│ tag        │  4 │
└────────────┴────┘
```

Comment: The tags group has duplicates, so it's not directly working as I expected. In real data it explode on rows.

Comment: @chaim then I don't really understand what do you expect as a result.

Comment: please explain how this code solve the problem

Comment: @DennyCrane I've updated the question with a possible desired output. It should explain itself clear than me :)

Comment: @chaim you need the summap func